# How to float menu list elements

Tags: html, css

I want to get my unordered list to sit next to the div tag I have to represent my homepage. I can't figure out how to get them to set next to each other. They seem to have the same size block but I don't know what to do to get them to sit next to each other properly.

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Homepage </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="nav-bar">
      <div class="head-title"><a href="#">Homepage</a></div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
}
.head-title{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    padding:14px;
    padding-right:16px;
    background-color:green;
    margin:0px;
}
.menu ul
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px;
}
.menu li
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:14px;
    background-color:orange;
    margin:0px;
    float:left;
}
.nav-bar
{
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-top:0px;
    float:left;
}
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: getbootstrap.com  I highly recommend using a CSS framework like Bootstrap.  It will solve a million problems and save you time.

Comment: You should write `ul.menu` instead of `.menu ul`

Comment: @Dreamwalker and open a doorway to million other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `ul.menu` not `.menu ul`

```
ul.menu
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0;     /* this might also help */
}
```

Here's an extended version with load of fixes:

```css
html, body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
}
.nav-bar{
  background-color:blue;
}
.head-title{
  padding:14px;
  padding-right:16px;
  background-color:green;
  float:left;
}
ul.menu{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.menu li{
  background-color:orange;
  float:left;
}
ul.menu li a{
  display: block;
  padding: 14px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-bar">
  <div class="head-title"><a href="#">Homepage</a></div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

like i.e:

- Never add padding to menu LI's. Style the inner `a` instead.
- inline-block on floated elements makes no sense
- etc...

http://jsbin.com/xifati/1/edit?html,css,output